# A memmove() Function with O(1) Time Complexity

Tags: c, memory

I was given this question during an interview today and am perplexed. I have tried Googling to find an answer, but I have not found anything that helps. All the information I can find says that memcpy and memmove is O(n) time and I cannot find an implementation that would be O(1).

The C code question is below:

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap. Let’s assume that the prototype for memcpy() is:
>
> void memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
>
> The purpose of this exercise is to create an implementation of memcpy() that is robust to memory region overlapping. That is, if the destination memory area overlaps the source, then part of the source memory area can be overwritten. The function to implement will have the following prototype:
>
> void rti_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
>
> You are not allowed to use malloc() in the solution, however, memcpy() can be used.
>
> Example below:
>
> The "Mem addrs" line represents pointer/memory addresses.
>
> The "Content" line represents the value stored in memory/pointer addresses prior to calling rti_memmove().
>
> The line below "rti_memmove(D, S, 5)" represents the data at the memory/pointer addresses after calling the rti_memmove() function.
>
> D = destination address
>
> S = source address
>
> n = number of bytes to move

```
n = 5      S     D
Mem addrs  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Content:   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
rti_memmove(D, S, 5);
Content:   a  b  c  d  c  d  e  f  g
```

> Because we deal with real time systems, memmove
>   must have a constant run time (aka a time complexity of O(1)).

The answer I came up with is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rti_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) 
{
  int i;

  if(src < dest)
  {
    for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
       *(dest+i) = *(src+i);
    }
  }
  else if(src > dest)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       *(dest+i) = *(src+i);
    }
  }
  else //src == dest
  {
    return;
  }

} /* rti_memmove() */
```

However, this answer is O(n) and the interviewer asked me how I would make it O(1). I couldn't/can't come up with an answer. We discussed possibly optimizing it using memcpy() for the non-overlapped bytes and the for loop for the overlapped bytes (Note that memcpy() has undefined behavior when copying memory that overlaps). We also discussed using some sort of fixed length buffer to memcpy() the src data to before using memcpy() to copy from the buffer to the destination. But this would be inefficient.

Currently, my only idea (after the Googling and thinking about the problem) is to limit the value of the *n* parameter to a specific value. For instance, if I had an if statement `if (n>512) return;` then the function would at max have a for loop with O(512) -> O(1) time and would have a predictable max runtime potentially meeting the real-time scheduling requirement of being constant.

TL;DR
How to make the code above run in O(1) time following the requirements listed.

Comment: In a literal/physical `memmove`, this is provably impossible: Given arbitrary input and some output buffer that does not overlap the input, then n bytes of memory in the output buffer **must** be set, and therefore the time must be O(n). The interviewer may have been considering some non-physical `memmove` such as having some number of buffers being managed and `memmove` from one to another would merely change pointers to which buffer the data was in. Or the interviewer may have been wrong. Or they may have been posing an impossible problem to see how you would analyze it.

Comment: you can use the DMA. then the function will have a O(1) but the transfer itself will run in the background much longer

Comment: You can't use `malloc` but can you use a VLA (i.e. `unsigned char temp[n];` in your function), then `memcpy` to/from that?

Comment: @P__J__ well, you could just signal another thread to do the copying.  All such functions would be better labelled 'startMemMove' and take a completion function as an argument:)

Comment: Even for real time, knowing that it's O(1) is not useful unless you know what the constant is.  In some sense it's already O(1), as the running time is bounded by the total size of memory, which is a constant.

Comment: Off the subject, but I wonder how the prospective employer is going to feel about having their interview question copy/pasted to SO...

Comment: I think the end of Eric's comment is a good point.  That question may not have been testing your algorithm design skills, but a skill that is perhaps even more important to a software engineer: how do you explain to your boss that the requirements you've been given are impossible to satisfy?

Comment: @NateEldredge probably 'if this candidate cannot keep interview questions to themselves, employing them would risk other company-confidential data.  Bin that CV, next....'

Comment: `if(src < dest)` is UB as C has no  defined way to order pointers unless they point to elements within the same array,

Comment: To make code technically `O(1)`, do `n` operations moving and `SIZE_MAX-n` operations  wasting time.  Then each `rti_memmove()` effort is O(SIZE_MAX), a constant.

Comment: I suspect the interviewer is looking for  `if()` blocks looking for 3 sections: portion of source _before_ destination,  _overlapping_ portion, portion of source _after_ destination.  Each block using `memcpy()` to do the copy - in a mistaken understanding that `memcpy()` are O(1).  This cannot be done in portable C without `memmove()` or a large temp space or UB.

Comment: danielcoolidge Why did you code `int i;` and not a type matching `size_t n`?

Comment: @AdrianMole The interviewer told me that I can't use a VLA of dynamic size (ie char buf[n]) but seemed to say I could have a fixed length buffer? However, memcpy() is O(n) which would make my function O(2n) if I use a buffer and memcpy() twice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica and EricPostpischil After some research that was essentially my conclusion as well; that he was giving me an impossible problem or was mistaken in thinking that memcpy() is O(1). He and I discussed that memcpy() could be used to copy non overlapping memory regions (and he gave me the impression that this was more efficient than the for loop).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Didn't think about using size_t at the time. Was more focused on making it work logically. Also, I'm not sure about the `if(src < dest)` part. The interviewer told me what I did was correct but not the time complexity desired.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's what I was thinking afterwards. That I could limit the `n` parameter to a constant which would make the function have a known max run time. But that didn't seem like a good solution being that memory moves could require multiple calls to memmove().

Comment: @NateEldredge Also, I am a new grad and am new to interview coding questions. I  didn't realize that posting the question (or my interpretation of it as a lot of what he said was verbal) was frowned upon or restricted since there's no verbal or written notice. I was just perplexed and wanted some input as to how to get the desired solution. Hopefully he will send me his solution since I asked for it (his response was he had to ask his team).

Comment: @danielcoolidge "The interviewer told me what I did was correct" not only implies an incorrect understanding of C, but that the interviewer was looking for a particular answer.  Sounds like they want [group think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink).  I see the solution as as [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092574/a-memmove-function-with-o1-time-complexity?noredirect=1#comment108093265_61092574) with the overlapping middle part done by walking up or down (depending on `src>dest`) then repeat with a fixed size `tmp[]` `src->tmp->dest`.